# Using PHP sessions to open new android activity

Tags: php, android, mysql, session

I have created the following PHP in order to check if some username already exists inside a database.

If it exists and the username+password is correct, I had like to open a new activity in android, for example profile page.

The PHP code looks as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();

$DATABASE_HOST = "XX";
$DATABASE_USER = "XX";
$DATABASE_PASS = "XX";
$DATABASE_NAME = "XX";

$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    die ('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}

if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
}

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
    $stmt->fetch();
    if ($_POST['password'] === $password) {

        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect password!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect username!';
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

So basically, if the login is successful, a session named `"loggedin"` is created. However how can I use it in android to open new activity?

Something like:

```
if (session == "loggedin"){
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, profile.class));
}
```

I also tried to use the echo message for example:

```
if ($_POST['password'] === $password) {

        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';
    } else {
        echo 'good';
    }
} else {
    echo 'bad';
}
```

And then in my android studio to check if the result that I read from the echo was `good` or `bad` and based on it to open activity however Im sure there are better ways.

Thank you

Comment: first off looking at the code it means you stored your passwords in plain text? second, you can at least respond with a json string

Comment: Yes for this example I didnt use hash for the password but thank you for noticing, will use at the final code =]. Can you please explain the json respond?

Comment: `$_POST['password'] === $password)`  Don't store plaintext... See [Safe Password Hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) ... Also `===` is designed to do the check as fast as possible as it will short circuit when it's false.. So that makes `===`prone for [timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack)

Comment: Also `} else {
        echo 'Incorrect password!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect username!';
}` is giving way to much information, you hint a possible hacker when a username is there which makes a bruteforce much more easy... You should use more general message more or less like *"The combination of username password is incorrect"*

Comment: Thank you mate, I use them in my original code, I just removed because I thought it will simplify my question. Will use your tip.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is Deep Linking.

Here's a link that will give you a short summary

http://www.codecastra.com/deep-linking-mobile-app-website/